# Guardar registros con una columna heterogenea

Tags: java, mongodb, spring, spring-boot, mongoose

Tengo dos preguntas:

1ª Cuestión.

Tengo que crear un objeto que me llegue al controlador con un campo que puede ser heterogeneo(con esto quiero decir que puede ser cualquier cosa, un JSON pero que contenga X variables con X datos).
¿Cómo puedo tratar este campo desde el controlador? Object? Strings = JSON?

Ejemplo:

```
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "Colorado Springs",
        "addressRegion": "CO",
        "postalCode": "80840",
        "streetAddress": "100 Main Street"
      },
      "personalFiles": [
           {
              "data": "Click Here",
              "size": 36,
              "style": "bold",
              "name": "text1",
              "hOffset": 250,
              "vOffset": 100,
              "alignment": "center",
              "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
          },
            {
            "Sid": "Allow Public Access to All Objects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
          }
      ],
      "document": "S3904529I"
      
    }
```

```
public final class Person {
    private final PostalAddress address;
    private final String document;
    private final List<Object> personalFiles;
}
```

**Faltan datos como IDs, variables, tipos, etc. Solo me interesa el Objeto personalFiles**

¿cómo podría guardar esos datos? ¿Lista de jsons? ¿Lista de mapas?
.

2º Cuestión, quiero guardar en BBDD ese objeto PersonalFiles: ¿que sería mejor guardarlo como arrays de String (JSON) o guardarlo como un mapa en otra tabla?

Comment: **quiero guardar en BBDD** ¿En qué BBDD?. Hablas de *mapa en otra tabla*, ¿es una Base de Datos relacional (MySQL, Oracle, MariaDB, SQLServer)?. El atributo o propiedad llamado `"personalFiles"` es un `Array` o lista de JSON's, por lo tanto lo que debes hacer en primer lugar es analizar (*parse*) el JSON que recibes y luego obtener el valor de la propiedad o clave `"personalFiles"`. Saludos

Comment: Perdón, me referia a una BBDD MongoDB.

Comment: Y si, puede ser que venga una lista de 0 a N elementos de personaFiles, pero cuando los cojo, no sé si guardarlos en BBDD como un String (JSON), o si leer los datos y crear un mapa, y este mapa, guardarlo de alguna manera en BBDD. No sé que sería más óptimo.

Comment: MongoDB almacena documentos, de hecho almacena objetos llamados BSON, los cuales son una representación Binaria de JSON. Puedes almacenar directamente un documento JSON en MongoDB, para ello tendrías que hacer el *cast* apropiado para insertar en alguna colección, los datos recibidos. Ahora bien, visto el ejemplo de lo que recibes, ¿cómo o qué pretendes guardar en la Base de Datos? ¿A qué te refieres con *más óptimo*? Tu pregunta se basa entonces en opiniones, lo cual es motivo de cierre. Saludos